# Disable enter key and space if iframe body is empty onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**How to check if iframe content is empty then then disable "enter key" and "space" 
else if Enable.**

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/q1ed0ph0/)

```
var iframeContainerVal = $("#textEditor").contents().find("body").text();
var container = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;

function checkPress(){
    alert('In Fn')
    $(container).keypress(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keycode == 32  ) {
            alert('aaa');
            event.preventDefault();
        }       
    });
}

if(iframeContainerVal == true) {
    checkPress()
}
else {
    alert('false')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false;`

```
function checkPress(){
    alert('In Fn')
    $(container).keypress(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 32  ) { 
            return false;            
        }       
    });
}
```

you used `event.keycode == 32` in your If statement **But,** it should capital C in keycode like
`event.keyCode == 32`

Comment: Thanks, But still same functionality, its not taking for space & If text is typed, it has to allow enter and space

Comment: Thanks, Only If text is typed, it has to allow enter and space

Answer (score 0):

Check for `iframe` empty content , iframe **id = 'if'**

```
if ($('#iframe').contents().find('body').children().length == 0) {
    alert('I frame is empty');
    if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
}
```